# docker-compose - env vars based on the ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have 2 services running - my website and the API.

In my code for the website I specified that it should use the API that has `port` equal to `API_PORT` env var.

My question: is there a way to set the `API_PORT` variables based on the ports from api service?

Overview of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
api-service:
    ...otherconfig
    ports:
      - 8009:8009
website:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inject the `API_PORT` env var into your compose file too:

`export API_PORT=8009`

then in the compose file

```
api-service:
    ...otherconfig
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}
website:
    ...
```